# How to replace this html using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this html.

```
<div>
  <input type="password" id="user_password" name="user_password"
         class="password">

  <div class="passwordstrength s_1" style="display: block;">bad</div>

  <input type="password" id="user_password_confirm"
         name="user_password_confirm" class="password"
         style="display: inline-block;">
</div>
```

i want to reset and replace it back to

```
<div>
  <input type="password" id="user_password" name="user_password"
         class="password">

  <div class="passwordstrength" style="display: none;"></div>

  <input type="password" id="user_password_confirm"
         name="user_password_confirm" class="password"
         style="display: none;">
</div>
```

how do i do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you want to modify the first example to become the second (and not that you have the second example on the page too, and want to replace the entire first example with the second), it looks like all the differences can be addressed with the following:

```
$(".passwordstrength").removeClass("s_1").empty().hide();
$("#user_password_confirm").hide().val("");
$("#user_password").val("");
```

The differences:

- `.passwordstrength` does not have the class `s_1` (that's the [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) part)
- `.passwordstrength` has no text inside it (that's the [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) part)
- `.passwordstrength` is hidden (this and the next are the [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) parts)
- `#user_password_confirm` is hidden
- The values of the 2 `input` elements are reset (that's the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) parts)

Comment: and how do i reset all the value too?

Comment: You can use `.val("")` to reset the value of an `input`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$('user_password').parent().html('you html does here');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.passwordstrength').css('display','none');
$('#user_password_confirm').css('display','none');
```

No need for html-replacement. You are trying to hide these fields?

Comment: yes i am trying to hide this fields. and i kind of hate html replacement.

Comment: Then the code I posted should work. You should however (as already suggested), add a ID for each field and use that ID to hide them. You can also replace `.css('display','none')` with `.hide()`, but hide() runs thought a lot of code in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".passwordstrength").removeClass("s_1").val('').hide();
$("#user_password_confirm").val('').hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add IDs to the two DIVs...

```
<div id="div1">
    <input type="password" id="user_password" name="user_password" class="password">
    <div class="passwordstrength s_1" style="display: block; ">bad</div>
    <input type="password" id="user_password_confirm" name="user_password_confirm" class="password" style="display: inline-block; ">
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <input type="password" id="user_password" name="user_password" class="password">
    <div class="passwordstrength" style="display: none; "></div>
    <input type="password" id="user_password_confirm" name="user_password_confirm" class="password" style="display: none; ">
</div>
```

then you can set this using the following statement:

```
$('#div1').html($('#div2').html());
```

Comment: bad idea, do you want me to add extra field just to replace the content.